# How to initialize class with argument "PaintEventArgs e" in C#

Tags: c#, graphics

I have my Gallow class which is responsible for rendering the gallow using e.Graphics, I need to use the object elsewhere and therefore it must be initialized at the beginning, but there I don't have access to "PaintEventArgs e". So how can I create an object with the argument "PaintEventArgs e"?

```
internal class Gallow: Hangman
{

    public Graphics g;

    public Gallow(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.g = e.Graphics;
    }
}
//...

Gallow gallow = new Gallow(e);
```

Comment: If you plan to instantiate this object in response to an event, you just pass the PaintEventArgs that was passed to the event. If you plan to instantiate this object outside of an event, and plan on keeping it around for a while, you can create your own instance of `Graphics` using [`CreateGraphics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Don't forget to `Dispose()` it!

Comment: `Gallow gallow = new Gallow(PaintEventArgs e);` should read `Gallow gallow = new Gallow(e);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PaintEventArgs e` should not be cached in a field. Always use the `e` which is passed. It's not 'yours'. It belongs to an object which is some higher in the callstack. This owner instance is might recreate the `Graphics` instance on size changes etc.

Instead of painting directly on the control, you'd better create a bitmap, which you can blit to the `Graphics` of the `e` parameter. Create the bitmap ones and recreate the bitmap on resizing the control (of applicable). It's what John Wu advices.

I assume that you are using winforms.

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // your gallow class instance.
    private readonly Gallow _gallow = new();

    // default constructor
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if the backpage and the bitmap have the same dimensions.
        _gallow.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // when the size is changed, we need a repaint.
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

_This will draw lines directly onto the form, so you see all lines draw separately. This will slow it down.

---

And via a bitmap:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // the field for the bitmap.
    private Bitmap _bitmap;
    
    // your gallow class instance.
    private readonly Gallow _gallow = new();

    // default constructor
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // on the Form_Load, (then the size is know) create the initial bitmap.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    }

    // on the paint even, check if the bitmap needs to be resized.
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if the backpage and the bitmap have the same dimensions.
        if (_bitmap.Width != Width || _bitmap.Height != Height)
        {
            // dispose the old one.
            _bitmap?.Dispose();
            // recreate the bitmap with a new size.
            _bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        }

        // draw you gallow graphics on the Graphics object.
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap))
            _gallow.Draw(g);

        // copy the bitmap to the form.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bitmap, 0, 0, _bitmap.Width, _bitmap.Height);
    }

    private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // when the size is changed, we need a repaint.
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

_This will draw lines first on a bitmap and ones it is ready, it will copy the bitmap to the form.

---

And here is the `gallow` class: (for testing)

```
internal class Gallow
{
    private readonly Random _rnd = new();

    public void Draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        var width = (int)graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Width;
        var height = (int)graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Height;

        // some random lines....(for testing)
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            int x1 = _rnd.Next(width);
            int y1 = _rnd.Next(height);
            int x2 = _rnd.Next(width);
            int y2 = _rnd.Next(height);
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note that the gallow class does not cache the graphics instance. Also the gallow class isn't changed, because both bitmap and the form uses the Graphics.*

Comment: Why not simply pass the PaintEventArgs' `Graphics` object to the `Draw()` method of the class? A Bitmap is not actually need -- The SizeChanged event is also not needed, you simply add `ResizeRedraw = true;` in the Constructor of the Form -- Assuming the OP is actually using WinForms Controls for the rendering

Comment: @Jimi that is the first example. (only forgot to remove the bitmapcreation there) Without the bitmap, you see each line appear on the screen (build up), instead of the complete drawing)